# Best Way to do a JOIN on Product UPC varchar(20)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a JOIN on two Tables. Each table contains a UPC varchar2(20) from different data sources.

What makes this JOIN  a bit difficult is that the values of UPC can vary in size, can sometimes be padded with leading zeros, and sometimes not. All contain a trailing check digit.

For example:

```
        Table 1               Table 2
UPC     "00000123456789"           "123456789"
             "234567890"           "234567890"
        "00000003456789"      "00000003456789"
               "3456799"      "00000003456799"
```

My thoughts are to convert each to a long and then do the compare.  Or I can append leading zeros.  Or an do a contains.

What is the best way to do the join using SQL?

Comment: How often are you going to do this? is this a one-off query/report or something that will live in production?

Comment: This join will be in a View, which would run several times a day.  The tables contains about 100k rows.

Comment: The reason I asked is, the frequency of use informs the effort to get it to perform. CASTing and CONVERTing means indexes are not going to be used, but if you're only doing this once or twice, who cares? We created a 'shadow field' for a part number field that gets auto-computed without punctuation to facilitate searches - we've indexed it. You might consider the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select * from 
table1 inner join table2 
on (CAST(CAST(table1.UPC AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR))
            =(CAST(CAST(table2.UPC AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR))
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/addd1/5)**

or

```
select * from 
table1 inner join table2 
on (RIGHT(table1.UPC,(LEN(table1.UPC) - PATINDEX('%[^0]%',table1.UPC)) + 1))
            =(RIGHT(table2.UPC,(LEN(table2.UPC) - PATINDEX('%[^0]%',table2.UPC)) + 1))
```

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/addd1/4)**

Comment: This needs to use bigint. UPCs are too large, in most cases, to cast to int. Also, if user input (or garbage in / garbage out) is involved, this may involve type conversion errors. I deal with e-commerce systems all the time, and the UPC data always causes problems.

Comment: I like your solution overall!

Comment: BTW, for Oracle, here is the equivalent SQL:  

    SELECT i.* 
    FROM table1 i 
    JOIN table2 p 
      ON (SUBSTR(i.UPC, -(LENGTH(i.UPC) - regexp_count('%[^0]%', i.UPC)) + 1))
        =(SUBSTR(p.UPC, -(LENGTH(p.UPC) - regexp_count('%[^0]%', p.UPC)) + 1))

Comment: `decimal(20,0)` might be a better idea than `bigint`, because `bigint` won't cover values larger than `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` (which is not even 20 digits).

Answer (score 2):

This is not the highest-performance option, but it is the simplest:

```
SELECT
  T1.UPC,
  T2.Column1
FROM
  myTable T1
  INNER JOIN myTable T2 ON
    RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 20) + T2.UPC, 20) = RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 20) + T1.UPC, 20)
```

Alternatively, you can create computed columns for these padded UPCs, and place indexes upon them. However, this comes with a slew of restrictions. I have not been able to use this in the real world very many times.

[Indexes on Computed Columns (MSFT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to add columns to your table, you could have persisted computed columns to just cast your varchar to bigint.  Then they can be indexed and the joins on these would be a lot quicker.  In apps where there are way more reads than writes, this can be worthwhile.

```
create table ack
(
    UPC
        varchar( 20 ) null,

    UPCValue 
        as isnull( convert( bigint, Upc ), 0 )  persisted
)
```

You don't have to do the isnull if Upc doesn't need to support null.

Answer (score 0):

Most UPC values are 12 digits, or 13 for the EAN variety (see http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Product_Code).  So if you can get away with altering your tables to make the column size match the expected value size that would be the simplest way.  You could alter the tables to be varchar(18) to allow for 5-6 leading zeros, while still allowing the values to safely be cast to bigint.  The maximum size of bigint is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (19 digits), so any numeric value stored in varchar(18) will fit.  Then you can query easily:

```
Select * 
From tab1
Join tab2 
on cast (tab1.upc as bigint) = cast(tab2.upc as bigint);
```

If you're stuck with varchar(20) columns, casting to bigint will still work assuming your actual data doesn't contain erroneous values that exceed the maximum size of bigint.  But obviously that isn't bulletproof.  A string of twenty nines ('99999999999999999999'), for example, will result in data truncation.

If you really need 20 digits you'll need to compare the strings by left-padding with zeros or trimming off the left zeros, as shown in some of the other answers.